# Backbone.js model event not triggering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got the following view file:

```
var BucketTransferView = Backbone.View.extend(
{
initialize: function(args)
{
    _.bindAll(this);
    this.from_bucket = args.from_bucket;
    this.to_bucket = args.to_bucket;
},
events:
{
    'click input[type="submit"]' : 'handleSubmit',
},
render: function()
{
    $(this.el).html(ich.template_transfer_bucket(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
},
handleSubmit: function(e)
{
    that = this;

    this.model.save(
        {
            date: 1234567890,
            amount: this.$('#amount').val(),
            from_bucket_id: this.from_bucket.get('id'),
            to_bucket_id: this.to_bucket.get('id')
        },
        {
            success: function()
            {
                // recalculate all bucket balances
                window.app.model.buckets.trigger(
                    'refresh',
                    [that.to_bucket.get('id'), that.from_bucket.get('id')]
                );
            }
        }
    );
    $.colorbox.close();
}
});
```

My buckets collection has this refresh method:

```
refresh: function(buckets)
{
    that = this;
    _.each(buckets, function(bucket)
    {
        that.get(bucket).fetch();
    });
}
```

My problem is that when the fetch() happens and changes the collection's models, it's not triggering change events in other view classes that has the same models in it. The view's models have the same `cid`, so I thought it would trigger.

What's the reason this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch will create new model objects.  Any view that's tied to the collection should bind to the collection's reset event and re-render itself.  The view's models will still have the same cid's because they're holding a reference to an older version of the model.  If you look at the `buckets` collection it probably has different cids.

My suggestion is in the view that renders the buckets, you should render all the child views and keep a reference to those views.  then on the reset event, remove all the child views and re-render them.

```
initialize: function()
{
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
    this._childViews = [];
},

render: function()
{
    _(this._childViews).each(function(viewToRemove){
        view.remove();
    }, this);

    this.collection.each(function(model){
        var childView = new ChildView({
            model: model
        });
        this._childViews.push(childView);
    }, this)
}
```

I hope this works for you, or at least gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: I assume you meant: `this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);` ?

Comment: This was different than how I'm rendering my lists (I was binding to the add event on the collection), but I hacked together a hybrid for now and it seems to work. It will be interesting to see if this works out well when there is a great number of items in the list.

Comment: Another approach:  If you know you're only changing 2 models (from_bucket and to_bucket), you can call fetch on just those 2 models and this won't create new models... then your views that are bound to those should detect the change event and you won't have to re-render all the views

Comment: Isn't that was I was originally doing? I was calling `collection.get(model.cid).fetch()`, which you explained would end up with a new cid, so events would not trigger.

I ended up calling collection.fetch() on the whole collection and re-rendering the whole thing. It works for now, but I'll look into a more efficient way of doing it, as I feel this won't work so well when the list gets longer than a handful of items.